# Magento Cart Price rules

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cart, shipping-methods, tax-class

1. I just want to ask, have a cart price rules on magento that if its equal or less than 349 AED the shipping is flat rate of 25 (This first rule is working fine) but if its equal or more than 350 it will be free shipping.(This Rule is not working fine. Because when i purchase 2000k it shows me 2 option of shipping method. The free shipping and the with shipping fee.) How can i fix this problem please. Please check the screenshot attach.

[image: Shipping Method Option] 
[image]
[image]

2. Tax I have a Tax rules that each product when they check out they will be automatically 5% added for VAT but on the summary it shows that TAX 0. How can i fix this. please check attach image.

[image: Tax Vat 5%]

Comment: Can someone help me on this problem please? Hope someone will help me thank you.